# How do I detect what characters are in pasted text?

Tags: javascript, html, character-encoding, copy-paste

I'm pasting text into an html table into multiple cells ( input areas within a form). It pastes fine when copied from Excel, as I'm breaking the lines and cells on the "\t" and "\n" characters. But from an html table, not so well.

How can I tell what characters are in my pasted text? I can process them once I know what they are.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Pasting into a web page TEXTAREA? A text editor containing HTML? Your question is not clear.

Comment: Fiddle would do just fine